# How to if elseif correctly with current SMARTY code?

Tags: smarty

I was converting everything from our existing bash scripts to use our new configuration. So after spending an hour, I noticed the bash scripts weren't even used! I noticed this after making changes didn't work. * facepalm*

Anyways, apparently the interface we use is based mainly on SMARTY templates. Now I want to create several rules, but I am not sure on the proper formatting. Maybe someone can jump in and advice me how to format it correctly?

The original piece of code is this:

```
    if (($data['mem'] != $_SESSION['vps'][$data['veid']]['orig']['memory']) && ($data['mem'] > 0))
    {
        $parameter .= " --kmemsize ".($data['mem']*203636).":".($data['mem']*224000);
        $query[] = "memory=".$data['mem'];
    }
```

Now what I want to do is something like this:

$mem < 768
then this should happen:

```
    $parameter .= " --kmemsize ".($data['mem']*2120000).":".($data['mem']*2140368);
```

$mem < 2048
then this should happen:

```
    $parameter .= " --kmemsize ".($data['mem']*706672).":".($data['mem']*727040);
```

else:

```
    $parameter .= " --kmemsize ".($data['mem']*203636).":".($data['mem']*224000);
```

How do I apply that based on the original code above?

Maybe someone can give me a workable example which I can use to apply it to the above code and create all the rules I need.

I am a bit worried, if I use wrong pieces of code, that I will mess up things. This is something I don't want obviously.

Thanks in advance.